# Proof of Kohn's theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, cold-atoms

In 1961 [W. Kohn's paper](http://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.123.1242) ( Phys. Rev. 123, 1242 (1961) ) first stated that the electron-electron interaction does not change the cyclotron resonance frequency in a bulk three dimensional gas.

I can understand the first 11 equations in this paper, but What does Eq. (12) mean and how to explicitly prove that the cyclotron frequency is not affected by interaction U?

Comment: Please include all relevant informations into the question, especially when linking to paywalled papers!

Comment: DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.123.1242

Answer (score 3):

Equation 12 is $H' = -\frac{e}{i \omega m} \mathcal{E}_- P_+ e^{i\omega t}$, where $\mathcal{E}_-$ is the strength of the AC electric field $\omega$ is its frequency, $m$ is the electron mass, $e$ is its charge, and the other quantities are defined in the text.

Plugging in the definitions, we find 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
H' &= \frac{ie}{\omega m} \mathcal{E}_- \left( P_x + i P_y \right) e^{i\omega t}\\
&=\frac{e \mathcal{E}_-}{\omega m}\left( P_x i e^{i\omega t} - P_y e^{i\omega t} \right).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now this $H'$ is not hermitation, so the real $H'$ is the hermitation part of this operator. That is, the real $H'$ is
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
H' &= \frac{e \mathcal{E}_-}{\omega m}\left( -P_x  \sin \omega t - P_y \cos \omega t \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{m} \mathbf{P} \cdot (e\mathbf{A}).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Where $\mathbf{P}$ is the vector momentum operator and $\mathbf{A}$ is the vector potential defined by $\mathbf{A} = \dfrac{\mathcal{E}_-}{\omega}(-\sin \omega t, -\cos \omega t, 0)$. Notice this vector potential corresponds to the electric field $\mathbf{E} = -\dot{\mathbf{A}}=\mathcal{E}_-(\cos \omega t, -\sin \omega t,0)$. That is $\mathbf{A}$ gives you a rotating magnetic field of magnitude $\mathcal{E}_-$. Also the hamiltonian perturbation $H' =\frac{1}{m} \mathbf{P} \cdot (e\mathbf{A})$ is exactly what you expect to get when you subject your particles to an external vector potential $\mathbf{A}$. So we see that his $H'$ is just the perturbation produced by imposing an external rotating electric field.

As far as proving that the interaction does not effect the cyclotron frequency, that is essentially done after he proves the commutation relation in equation 5. For after equation 5, he only uses equation 5, which, because it makes no reference to $U$, must be valid in the case $U=0$. It is obvious that $U$ does not affect equation 5 because the contribution of $U$ towards $[H,\mathbf{P}]$ is the same as the contribution of $U$ towards $\dot{\mathbf{P}}$, but we know (by conservation of momentum) that internal forces cannot cause a change in momentum.

Comment: NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs, Thank you so much for your answer. The first part is very clear. But I am still a little confused by the second part. Is it possible to write down the formula of cyclotron frequency with interaction, and prove it is the same as without interaction?

Comment: I will try to narrow in on your confusion. Which of the following two things are you confused about, 1, 2 or both? 1: In the interacting case, $\dfrac{i}{\hbar} [H , \mathbf{P}] = -\dfrac{e}{mc} \mathbf{P} \times \mathbf{H}$ just as in the non-interacting case; or 2: if the above equation ($\dfrac{i}{\hbar} [H , \mathbf{P}] = -\dfrac{e}{mc} \mathbf{P} \times \mathbf{H}$) holds, then the energy spacing between levels different by one application of a ladder operator (and therefore the cyclotron frequency) is $\dfrac{\hbar e \mathcal{H}}{mc}$.

Comment: I have a question regarding @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs 's answer, and I have posted it as a new question. [physics.stackexchange.com/q/188380](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/188380)